# golang web programming tutorial code not working

Tags: web-applications, web, methods, struct, go

I'm trying to learn Go for web programming. I've been learning the language, and I've recently started [this](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_2) tutorial on the official site for the go language.

So far, I'm stuck on the Data Structures part. I've copied the code word for word.

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
)

type Page struct {
        Title string
        Body []byte
}

func (p *Page) save() (error) {
        filename := p.Title + ".txt"
        return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}

func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error) {
        filename := title + ".txt"
        body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}

func main() {
        p1 := &Page{Title: "TestPage", Body: []byte("WHADDUP!")}
        p1.save
        p2, _ := loadPage("TestPage")
        fmt.Println(string(p2.Body))
}
```

Running `$ go build wiki.go` gives me the following:

```
# command-line arguments
./main.go:30: p1.save evaluated but not used
```

What is it that I have wrong? It seems to me like I've copied the code word for word, except for the string that's saved to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p1.save` is a function so, written like this, it doesn't do anything, which is what the compiler is "warning" you about (but with Go, what could be a warning is in fact an error and prevents compilation).

What you might want is `p1.save()`, which unlike `p1.save` would actually run the function.

Comment: What's the difference between calling it without the parenthesis vs. with them?

Comment: @Hugo, when you write "p1.save" you are not actually calling the function. You are simply writing the name of the object, followed by the name of the function, and this doesn't do anything. Likewise, if you only write "p1", you'll get an error. Only a function name followed by parenthesis is a function call.